# How to Select Rows in a Datatable?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

How can I use the Variable **`Itmnmbr`** instead of hard-coding its value, `'i-2051'`?

```
Dim fr() As DataRow
Dim Itmnmbr As string = "i-2051"
fr = dt.Select("item = 'i-2051'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct way is to use an [Interpolated String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings), which are available from Visual Studio 2015, VB.Net 14:

```
Dim Itmnmbr As string = "i-2051"
fr = dt.Select($"item = '{Itmnmbr}'")
```

As a suggestion, let's change the names of Variables / Fields so it's easier to read them and also understand what these objects are used for. For example:

```
Dim dt as New DataTable()
'[...]
Dim itemNunmber As string = "i-2051"
Dim filteredRows As DataRow() = dt.Select(...)
```

`itemNunmber` is easier to read than `Itmnmbr` and `filteredRows` is more explicit than `fr`. There are some *convetions* that most are used to, as `dt` for DataTable, `ds` for DataSet etc., in this context. Better be sure that when you read your code after some time you don't get mad with yourself :)

Note that an Interpolated String is the same as a string formatted with [String.Format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format), so these two are actually the same thing:

```
Dim filteredRows As DataRow() = dt.Select($"item = '{itemNumber}'")
Dim filteredRows As DataRow() = dt.Select(String.Format("item = '{0}'", itemNumber))
```

Setting `Option Infer On` (should be `On` already), to make use of [local type inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-infer-statement), you can write:

```
Dim filteredRows = dt.Select($"item = '{itemNumber}'")
```

and let the compiler infer the Type. In Visual Studio, if you move the mouse pointer over the variable, it will tell you what Type that is.

You have other options, if you need more *dynamic* selections.
The [`DataTableExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions) (which require a Project Reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly - usually already linked along with `System.Data`), let you use the the [AsEnumerable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable) method.

In [LINQ to Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects) style:
Here, using the default string Comparer

```
Dim filteredRows = 
    dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(dr) dr("item").ToString().Equals(itemNumber))
```

Or in [LINQ to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/) style:
Here, using the [InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) for the comparison.

```
Dim filteredRows =
    From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
    Where row.Field(Of String)("item").Equals(itemNumber, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
    Select row
```

See also: [StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison) and [Best practices for comparing strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings)

These two last methods don't return an array of DataRow objects references, but a [EnumerableRowCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.enumerablerowcollection). The advantage is (when you can make use of it) that the collection is returned only when you actually use it (the execution is deferred).
When used correctly, it can improve the performance of your code. Try it out.

Instead of `DataTable.Select()`, you could also filter your DataTable, using its [DefaultView.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter) property.

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"item = '{itemNumber}'"
' You can save the filter to restore it later, if needed
Dim previousFilter = dt.DefaultView.RowFilter
```

When you present the Rows of your DataTable, only the Rows that meet the criteria defined by the Filter are shown (e.g., in a DataGrid of sort).

As mentioned, you're working with References here. The Collection of Rows returned by `DataTable.Select()` contain references of the Rows in the DataTable.

For example, if you consider the Collection and the filtered DataTable:

```
Dim filteredRows = dt.Select($"item = '{itemNumber}'")
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"item = '{itemNumber}'"
```

Assume that `filteredRows` contains a single Row. Then you apply a Filter.
If you now change the value of `filteredRows(0)("item")`:

```
filteredRows(0)("item") = "Some other value"
```

when you present your DataTable in a UI, no Rows will be shown, since the Filter is active and now none of the Rows meet the filter's criteria: setting `filteredRows(0)("item")` has changed the value of the Row it refers to.

To remove a Filter, set it to `string.Empty`:

```
 dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = Sting.Empty
```

To restore the previously saved filter:

```
 dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = previousFilter
```

Comment: When I use `Dim previousFilter = dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"item = '{itemNumber}'"` it does not change the display in a DataGridView. `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"item = '{itemNumber}'"` does filter the data. `previousFilter` is a Boolean and , it appears that the second `=` is a comparison, not an assignment. Where am I getting off track?

Comment: @Mary Yep, that's a too quick copy/paste (it was code-tested in C#, where the return value is a string, but that's not the way to set the filter anyway). I thought I changed it, instead I only modified and cut out the last line, where there was the same double assignment. Thanks for noticing. Edited.